# Do Threads running in different process can share same address space?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

Multiple Threads running in a same process share same address Space.
But if multiple Threads are running in different process can they share the same address space?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, using shared virtual memory.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#In_software

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there may be some weird operating system out there that has some weird definition of "process" and "thread" such that it is in fact possible for one process to directly access the memory of another process, but generally:

No. For all well-known, mainstream operating systems, it is within the definition of a "process" that it has its own address space.

The only way to accomplish this is by leveraging special functionality that might be offered by your operating system to explicitly map memory of one process into another. Such functionality falls under the category of "virtual memory", "memory mapping", etc.

Some operating system might not offer such functionality, but might offer something similar, such as "memory-mapped files". If the operating system makes it possible to map a file into the process memory, then you can have each process map the same file into its memory, and thus have both processes indirectly share the same memory. The disadvantage of this approach is that the operating system will keep needlessly writing any memory you modify to a disk file, even though you may have no use for a disk file.